# cups can't print the files, only the test page works fine ( HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125a USB CNB6H376TK HPLIP )

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, hplip

I am experiencing issues with my HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125a USB printer with serial number CNB6H376TK. I have installed the HPLIP (HP Linux Imaging and Printing) driver, the CUPS (Common UNIX Printing System) server, and the CUPS client on my Ubuntu system. However, when I try to print files from the CUPS client, it does not work, and an error occurs. The only thing that prints successfully is the test page.

**Interestingly**, after printing a test page, the error seems to magically fix itself temporarily. To print the file I want, I need to physically go to the printer and press the 'scan' button, after which the desired file gets printed.

I have shared my logs on Pastebin for a more detailed analysis of the error. Additionally, I would like advice on where else I could report this issue to get a fix.

I have tried all known manipulations with CUPS, but they did not help. I suspect the issue lies with the HPLIP driver. I have tried installing lower versions of HPLIP, but it either did not solve the problem or only fixed it temporarily, and after a few prints, the issue reoccurred. Previously, I was using Manjaro Linux and faced identical problems. I decided to switch to Ubuntu and installed everything from scratch, but that did not help either. Additionally, I observed the same issue on another computer when I changed the server.

pastebin -

> https://pastebin.com/GRh003Rk

Comment: The output of `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7` from the server would be useful.